# Structural architecture

Tags: vhdl

How does the compile know that the VHDL for component ND2 is a NAND gate?
Its just a name ND2....

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, there should be an `architecture` definition for ND2 somewhere in your code or in the libraries you reference.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comment by `The Photon` your compiler will not just create a NAND without you (or someone else) defining it somewhere. Every component has to be known, so there most likely is a file called `nd2.vhd` where you have a separate entity and architecture definition for the named component.
I assume this is some kind of exercise so this information might be just taken for granted and is not listed separately.